# Boolean error (Required Boolean ) in java

Tags: java

When the class `conector.conexion();` if I use the command:

```
if (conector.conexion()) {
}
```

```
Error : Required Boolean  `conector.conexion()`
```

What is wrong?

[image]

Comment: `conector.conexion()` is a `Connection` type not a `boolean`, what are you trying to do?

Comment: Please post [actual code](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) rather than a link to an image of code

Comment: As error message says, conector.conexion() doesnt return a boolean. What do you try to test ?

Comment: I'm going to check.**how to convert Boolean?**

Comment: don't do convert. there should be some boolean member in condition to make it running. `conexion` is not of type `boolean`.

Comment: @Jalalazad haji be farsi begu, che kar mikhay bokoni

Comment: سلام من قصد دام از کلاس کانکشن خودم در دستور شرطی استفاده کنم اما از من ارور میگیره ؟ چیکار کنم ؟

Comment: @Jalalazad che dastoori mikhay bedi?

Comment: Can you post code of `ConexionMysql` class ?

Comment: @nafasmikham dastory benevisam ke vaght Connection motasell shod biya in kara ro anjam bede?

Answer (score 1):

Connection is not Boolean type class.
Instead of `if(conector.conexion())` you can use like below :

```
if(conector.conexion() != null) {
  //It ensure connection is not null
  //To check connection is not closed
  if(!conector.conexion().isClosed()) {
   //code...
  } 
}
```

For Detail: [Connection Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html)

Answer (score 0):

Do following to check if connection instance has been created or not:

```
if(conector.conexion() != null){
     //code stuff
}
```